# How can I specify an application name when logging in?

Tags: api, security, soap-api, authentication

I was looking at the login history of my Salesforce API account and I noticed there was a column for application name.  I would love to be able to specify that when performing a login so I can determine which applications are logging in and when.

Right now I am using the SOAP version of their API, but, I didn't see a property I could specify when logging in.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**REST API**

When using the REST API you need to create a `Connected App` (Setup/Create/Apps).  The name of your connected application will be the name displayed in the application column.

If someone knows how to specify a name for the SOAP API I would welcome someone to update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For the Partner API try setting the [CallOptions.client](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_header_calloptions.htm#calloptions_client) to a string value before logging in.

This value is typically provided by Salesforce after you pass the security review and allows you to access Professional edition orgs.

Comment: I'm using the enterprise WSDL.